# Gspread Exception API Error Code 400 - Invalid Argument

Tags: python, exception, gspread

I've created two different variables which contain a list of user input results.  I've put those two variables into another variable so I can update a single row on my spreadsheet with this data.

However, I'm unable to do this because of this error:

```
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gspread/worksheet.py", line 1577, in append_row
    return self.append_rows(
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gspread/worksheet.py", line 1627, in append_rows
    return self.spreadsheet.values_append(range_label, params, body)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gspread/spreadsheet.py", line 150, in values_append
    r = self.client.request("post", url, params=params, json=body)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gspread/client.py", line 92, in request
    raise APIError(response)
gspread.exceptions.APIError: {'code': 400, 'message': 'Invalid values[3][0]: list_value {\n  values {\n    string_value: "john smith"\n  }\n  values {\n    string_value: "38"\n  }\n  values {\n    string_value: "mini"\n  }\n  values {\n    string_value: "cooper"\n  }\n  values {\n    string_value: "2003"\n  }\n}\n', 'status': 'INVALID_ARGUMENT'}
```

I can use either on or the other variables as mentioned above but not both at same time.  Is there another way which I can upload all of this data into the one row but with two or three or even four seperate uploads?  Would appreciate any kind of suggestion or thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

Completley forgot that I can split the lines of the list:

```
user_inputs = [
        username, user_age, 
        car_make, car_model, 
        car_year, one_input, 
        two_input, three_input]
```

This will allow me to input as many different variables into this list to be under one large variable which can be used to update the spreadsheet.

I think this would just be the simplest solution, unsure of any others at the moment.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It's actually pretty nice on its own. Splitting the list was the missing part for me.